# Unknown Factory in Ember.js Model Test

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a simple test on my Ember models. They work fine for models without relationships, but as soon as I introduce a relationship it doesn't work.

```
moduleForModel('climber', 'Climber', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
 needs: ['model:ascents']
});

test('it exists', function() {
  var model = this.subject();
  //var store = this.store();
  ok(model);
});
```

Here's the error:

```
Setup failed on it exists: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `model:ascents`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer ended up being that the model I was referencing needed to be singular and not plural:

```
needs: ['model:ascent']
```

Comment: I had a similar situation where all I needed to do was remove the space after the colon.